# File output shows crypted image in the begining of the output?

Tags: c

The program is supposed to show a menu and the user to make the choice by choosing the specified number.

The programs works well but when it comes to read the file content it begins with some cryptec symbols then it show the file content.
I tried all the solution like using other reding function for file but it's the same result

why shows these symbols ? and where they come from?

[image: The image below explain the encryptec symbols in the begining of the output]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
//functions protoype
void Menu(FILE *file);
void Add_Number(FILE*file);
void Show_Numbers(FILE *file);
void Search_Number(FILE *file);


//Define a struct
typedef struct {
    char firstName[20];
    char lastName[20];
    unsigned long number ;
}person;


//Main program
int main()
{
    FILE *file = NULL;
    //file = fopen("contacts.txt", "a+");
    Menu(file);
     return 0;
}


void Add_Number(FILE *file)
{
    person newUser;

    file = fopen("contacts.txt", "a");
    if (file != NULL)
    {
    printf("NOM:\n");
    scanf("%s",newUser.firstName);
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("Prenom:\n");
    scanf("%s",newUser.lastName);
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("Numero:\n");
    scanf("%lu",&(newUser.number));
    fflush(stdin);

    fprintf(file, "\n%s\t%s\t%lu", newUser.firstName, newUser.lastName, newUser.number);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Success");

    }

    else
    {
        printf("Erreur d'ouverture de fichier");
        exit(-1);
    }
    fclose(file);
}


void Show_Numbers(FILE*file)//FILE *file)
{
    person user;
    char s[100];
    file = fopen("contacts.txt", "a+");
    printf("%s", user.firstName);

    if (file != NULL)
    {
        fseek(file,1,0);
         while (fgets(s,1000,file)!=NULL)
         {
             printf("%s",s);
         }


        //while (fgets(test, 100, file) != NULL /*EOF*/) // On lit le fichier tant qu'on ne reçoit pas d'erreur (NULL)
           /* {
                printf("%s\n", test); // On affiche la chaîne qu'on vient de lire
            }*/

        fclose(file);


/*
            fg(file, "%s %s %lu\n", test);//, user.lastName, user.number);
            printf("Nom: %s\t\t", test);//user.firstName);
         //   printf("Prenom: %s\t\t", user.lastName);
          //  printf("Numero: %lu\n", user.number);*/


    }
     else
    {
        printf("Erreur d'ouverture de fichier");
        exit(-1);
    }
  fclose(file);
}


void Search_Number(FILE *file)
{
    file = fopen("contacts.txt", "a+");
    char userToFined[20];
    person user;
    //test if file not NULL
    if(file != NULL)
    {
            //input
        puts("saisir le numero a chercher\n");
        gets(userToFined);

        //read from the begging
        rewind(file);
        do
        {
            fscanf(file, "%s %s %lu", user.firstName, user.lastName, &user.number);
        }
        while (user.firstName != userToFined && !feof(file));

        if(user.firstName == userToFined)
        {
            printf("Success ! %s est trouve\n", user.firstName);
            printf("Son est prenom: %s\t\t", user.lastName);
            printf("Son numero est: %lu\n", user.number);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%s est introuvable", userToFined);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Erreur d'ouverture de fichier");
        exit(-1);
    }
    fclose(file);
}


void Menu(FILE *file)
{
int choice;
    do
    {
        puts("\n************************************************************\n\t\t BIENVENUE \t\t\n************************************************************");
        puts("\t \t **Choisir votre choix**\t \t\n");
        puts("---1---  Ajouter un nouveau contact\n");
        puts("---2---  Afficher le repertoire\n");
        puts("---3---  rechercher un numero\n");
        puts("---4---  Ajouter un nouveau contact\n");
        puts("Votre Choix:");
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            Add_Number(file); // Add user
            break;
        case 2:
            Show_Numbers(file); //Show repository
            break;
        case 3:
            Search_Number(file); //Search User
            break;
        case 4:
            exit(0);
            break;
        default:
           printf("Choix Invalid");
            break;
    }

    } while (choice != 4);
}
```

Comment: You've posted a picture of text, why not just post the text?

Comment: to show the crypted symbols in the output

Comment: But that did not require a shot of your entire screen! - use the Windows snipping tool at least.  The junk output can be posted as text in any case - you've even done that in a later comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `Show_Numbers()` has a number of issues:

```
void Show_Numbers(FILE*file)  //<<< WHY IS file AN ARGUMENT?
{
    person user;                         // <<<< DELETE THIS
    char s[100];
    file = fopen("contacts.txt", "a+");  // <<<< OPEN FOR READ-ONLY
    printf("%s", user.firstName);        // <<<< DELETE THIS
```

The variable `user` is unitialised, and then only used in the attempt to print an initialised value.  As such the two lined indicated serve no purpose whatsoever and is the cause of the junk output.

The file is opened for appending but never written to.

Passing `file` as an argument serves no purpose if you are opening and closing the file locally.  Use:

```
     FILE* file = fopen( "contacts.txt", "r" ) ;
```

instead, and pass no argument.

Then later:

```
     while (fgets(s,1000,file)!=NULL)
     {
         printf("%s",s);
     }
```

You are reading chunks of 1000 characters into a 100 character array array.

Finally but less critically, at the end of the function you unnecessarily close the file that is already closed earlier in the function.

```
  fclose(file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`user.firstName` is uninitialized in `Show_Numbers` when it is printed. Accessing uninitialized memory is undefined behavior. In this case your program interpreted whatever values were lying around in those memory addresses as a character string and printed that. It just so happened to be "×Í=ÿp■`".

```
person user;
printf("%s", user.firstName); // uninitialized, may print garbage
```

Also, `fgets(s,1000,file)` may write outside of the buffer. `s` is only 100 chars big, not 1000.

Comment: How did you initialize it? If you only meant to print the contents of contacts.txt, these two lines should probably be removed as they don't contribute to that.

Comment: @YoussefKhedher : Not sure I believe that you initialised it (at least not correctly), but surely just looking at that piece of the code has made you realise the error - ask yourself what those two lines are for?  They serve no purpose and are clearly the cause of the junk output.